# i can't create react project in chromebook

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debian, chromebook

harsh@penguin:~/practice$ npx create-react-app demoProject
Need to install the following packages:
create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y) y

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from the output? Where did that go wrong?

Comment: after i uninstall i try  npx create-react-app demoProject  again and same output